# Proving existence of a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty$$ 
Prove that $f$ has a minimum on $\mathbb{R}$; that is, there is an $x_m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x_m)=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)<\infty$$

I think the best approach would be to prove the existence of a lower bound, that is $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}:M<f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to do this.
I am probably supposed to use the extreme value theorem or the intermediate value theorem, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For any $a\in \mathbf R$, $K=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,f(a)]\bigr)$ is closed, and since $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, it is bounded. By the *extreme value theorem*, on this compact set, $f$ attains a minimum $m\le f(a)$, which is a minimum on $\mathbf R$ by the very definition of $K$: indeed, if $x\in\mathbf R\smallsetminus K$, $f(x)>f(a)\ge m$.

Comment: Rolle's theorem concerns *differentiable* functions, while the question requires $f$ only to be continuous.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I misread the question. I'll change my answer.

Comment: I don't quite follow, or understand what you mean by, " ... which is a minimum on $\mathbf R$ by the very definition of $K$". Could you expand and clarify this please?

Comment: Yes. I've added an explanation. Is that clearer?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Consider an example: $f(x)=x^2-1$ with $a=2$. Then $K=f^{-1}([0,3])=[-2,-1]\cup[1,2]$ and $m=0$. But $x=0\in\mathbf R\smallsetminus K$ and $f(x)=f(0)=-1<m$.

Comment: Oh! sorry, I forgot the function can be negative. Thanks for pointing the problem. I've modified the argument, it should be OK now.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple if you note the obvious fact that value of the function $f$ is always a real number although its limit may be $\pm\infty$. Let's for specificity set $A = f(0)$. Since $f(x) \to \infty$ when $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, it follows that there exists a real number $M > 0$ such that $f(x) > |A|$ for $x \geq M$ and $x \leq -M$. Consider the function $f$ on interval $[-M, M]$. Since it is continuous it has a minimum value on this interval. And clearly one of the values of $f$ in this interval is $A = f(0)$. Since $f(M)$ and $f(-M)$ are greater than $|A|$ it follows that the minimum value is attained at an interior point $c \in (-M, M)$. Further note that beyond the interval $[-M, M]$ the values of $f$ are greater than $|A|$ and hence these values are also greater than $f(c)$. It follows that $f(c)$ is the minimum value of $f$ on whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does your proof work for the existence of a minimum point on an open set ?

Comment: @Psylex: if $f$ is continuous on an open interval $(a, b) $ it may not have a minimum. For example consider $f(x) =x$ on $(0,1)$. So one must consider closed intervals.

Comment: I am trying to adapt your proof for the Gamma function defined on the open interval (0, infinity). On an open intervall it may work if the  function goes to infinity on the borders.  We could still find t and T positive such that gamma(x) is lower than gamma(2) if x is not in [t,T] then we conclude by compacity.   It's a bit like [-M,M] but with a translation, i guess?

Comment: @Psylex: yes, if the function tends to $\infty$ at end points then it will have a minimum. Same proof works with minor adaptation. Also Gamma function does have a minimum somewhere around $1.46$.

Comment: Thanks for the input ; )